# 405 Method now allowed when calling API project in multi project solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have two projects ion a single solution, a .NET Core 7 API App and a Client side Blazor app which communicates with the API App.

I am developing this in Visual Studio, and have set the startup project as the Client Side project so that the blazor app loads in my web browser when I run the project.

The solution is setup to build and run the API app along with the client side project.

When I run the solution, the API runs on http://localhost:4000 however, attempt to call the API result in 405 Method not Allowed.  The same result happens via Postman.

If I now switch the startup project to the API rather than the blazor client app - I can no longer use the blazor app, however I can still test the API in Postman on the same address and the API will now work.

In API app, I have also added the following to the Program.cs file:

```
app.UseCors(x => x
.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader());
```

I cannot figure out what could be wrong with my project setup, any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with CORS - you'd get a specific error message stating that. 405 method not allowed sounds like you are trying to call an endpoint with the wrong method (e.g. doing `GET` request to `POST` endpoint)

Comment: As randomslav said, you can use Startup Project and select Multiple. You can also open the exe alone to run one of them, but then you won't be able to debug that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run **both** API and Client side app.

Right click on *Solution* -> *Properties* → *Common Properties* → *Startup Project* and select *Multiple startup projects*.

[image]